# Many concurrent connections with socket.io

Tags: node.js, windows, sockets, socket.io

I am new to node.js/socket.io and trying to build a performant socketserver which needs to withstand a lot concurrent, persistent connections. To test the limits I built a client which creates 10k websockets and I don't experience any issues.  However when I increase this number to 20k it will cause issues. Server and client are running on the same machine (windows 10).

**The issue I am experiencing:**

Once I exceed 16k concurrent connections I get the following error message for my client:

> engine.io-client:socket socket error
>   {"type":"TransportError","description":{"code":"ENOBUFS","errno":"ENOBUFS","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":5433,"type":"error","target":{"domain":null,"_events":{},"_eventsCount":4,"_socket":null,"_ultron":null,"_closeReceived":false,"bytesReceived":0,"readyState":0,"supports":{"binary":true},"extensions":{},"_isServer":false,"url":"ws://127.0.0.1:5433/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket","protocolVersion":13,"binaryType":"buffer"}}}
>   +0ms

**I have tried the following to fix this issue:**

1. Increasing the available RAM for the node proccess by using the followwing node startparameter: `--max-old-space-size=8192`
2. Clustering (multiple client proccesses)

**Notes:**

1. The machine which is running these applications has 16gb RAM. 8gb RAM is free when both applications are running.
2. The server loses socket connections once exceeding the specific amount of socket connections (because of ping timeouts I think).
3. CPU only spikes to 100% when creating all sockets, otherwise it's "idling" at 25% cpu.

**The code I am using for the client:**

```
var helper=require("./helpers/helper.js");

function log(text){
    console.log("[CLIENT] " + text);
}

var blocked = require("blocked");
blocked(function(ms){
    console.log("[WARNING] Last client tick took " + ms + "ms!! Clients may not react fast enough....");
}, {threshold: 150});

function createClient(){
    var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://127.0.0.1:5433', {transports:['websocket']});

    socket.on('response', function (data) {
        console.log("server:" + JSON.stringify(data));
    });

    socket.on('sessionCheckResponse', function (data) {
        //console.log("server:" + JSON.stringify(data));
    });

    socket.connect();

    setInterval(function () {
        socket.emit("sessionCheck", "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccccccccccccc");
    }, 2500);
}

for(var i=0; i<17000; i++)
    createClient();
```

Comment: Could you care to explain why the client needs to do 16k of connections?

Comment: 16k is the Limit which still Works. The Client just Simulates 16k connections to Stress test the Server. In Production i Need to Händle 50-100k connections (with Better Hardware though)

Comment: But aren't you getting the error on the client? Because it seems to me that you are doing a stress test on the client. Try creating new connections with a timeout,  instead of creating 17k in a for loop

Comment: @FabioAntunes This results in the same problem. And yes I get this issue on my client

Comment: I stand by my point, that this is more a client stress test than a server test. It's your server that needs to be able to handle 16k, 50k, 100k or wtv not your client. Try creating multiple client instances with 10k each or less connections and you can even use some computers on your network to connect to your server, making the test more real.

Comment: @fabio antunes he said he tried to use clustering on the client to fix it from what I understand. (many client processes each only starting just a few thousand connections) but trying to add more machines as clients would definitely be a good idea!

Comment: As Felheart said I actually tried running multiple clients (2x 15k) but I still don't manage to accept/handle more connections than 14k with my server. There is no error message at all, so I posted the error message which happens client sided. I assumed that it is an OS setting or node setting which I have to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution can be found here (editing the MaxUserPort value in the registry), only applies to windows environments obviously: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/196271